# Calling WCF with Ajax - 404 Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I've been trying to follow this [article](http://www.encodedna.com/wcf/tutorial/invoke-a-wcf-service-method-with-multiple-parameters.htm) and create a WCF Service to access with an Ajax call. I am getting a 404 on my Ajax call and have no idea why because it looks ok to me. Can someone please help me fix the 404 error and show me where I have a namespace or whatever wrong?

Before anyone yells at me, I have never created a WCF service (let alone call it from Ajax) so I am following the article, which says do not worry about an interface right now :)

```
namespace SearchService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Search
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        public string SearchFiles(string searchText)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                string currentFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\somefolder\views\filteredViews\");

                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(currentFolder, "*.htm");

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);

                    if (contents.Contains(searchText))
                    {
                        result.AppendLine(file);
                        result.Append("|");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}

<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="SearchServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webEndPointBehavior">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                               multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="SearchService.Search" behaviorConfiguration="SearchServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" 
                      contract="SearchService.Search" 
                      binding="webHttpBinding" 
                      behaviorConfiguration="webEndPointBehavior" 
                      name="webEndPoint" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>

var Type;
var Url;
var Data;
var ContentType;
var DataType;
var ProcessData;

$("#searchButton").click(function () {
    var searchText = $("#searchText").val();
    Type = "POST";
    Url = "Search.svc/SearchFiles";
    Data = '{"' + searchText + '"}';
    ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    DataType = "json";
    varProcessData = true;
    CallService();
});

// Function to call WCF  Service       
function CallService() {
    $.ajax({
        type: Type,                 //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url,                   // Location of the service
        data: Data,                 //Data sent to server
        contentType: ContentType,   // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType,         //Expected data format from server
        processdata: ProcessData,   //True or False
        success: function(msg) {    //On Successfull service call
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed        // When Service call fails
    });
}

function ServiceFailed(result) {
    alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
    Type = null;
    varUrl = null;
    Data = null; 
    ContentType = null;
    DataType = null;
    ProcessData = null;
}

function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
    if (DataType == "json") {
        alert("It worked" + result);
    }
}

function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
    if (xhr.responseText) {
        var err = xhr.responseText;
        if (err)
            error(err);
        else
            error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a space between var and ProcessData.  your code->varProcessData = true;

Comment: Also, is your ajax call hitting SearchFiles method?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh, thanks for the catch. I fixed it, with no change to the 404. And I am not hitting SearchFiles. When I click submit, it goes to ServiceFailed and I see a 404 in the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that my service was setup correctly. The problem arose when I tried to call it from Ajax. It seems that instead of putting this in the Ajax call:

```
Url = "Search.svc/SearchFiles";
```

I needed to have this in the Ajax call:

```
url: "http://localhost:57761/Search.svc/SearchFiles"
```

Unless I missed this in my searching (or I am sort of still wrong), that is all it took.

If anyone cares to explain this further (or especially add a link that explains the difference), please do.